# How do I indent text region after \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, indentation

I want to indent the text region under the graphics (`\includegraphics`). However, using `\indent` doesn't work properly.

[image]

How do I indent, like text is indented after a newline?

Comment: did you start the paragraph after the image with `\par`?

Comment: `\includegraphics` has no space or position rules attached to it, it is just like a letter so your question is the same as "how do I indent after the letter `G`" and answer is just to start a paragraph. ???

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `\par` shouldn't often be needed in a document, where it's more usual to use a blank line (which is the same thing)

Answer (score 3):

It mostly depends on how you include the graphics. I suggest, for this case, using `\[...\]` as shown below.

Since I don't have your graphics, I recreated it with `tikz-cd`, which has the advantage of using the same font as the document.

Note that a blank line after `\]` will cause indentation in the following line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2] This is illustrated in the following diagram:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5em,row sep=3em]
{} \arrow[r,"\textstyle\textbf{Compile}"]
   \arrow[dr,swap,"\textstyle\textbf{Interpret}"]
&
{} \arrow[d,"\textstyle\textbf{Run}"]
\\
{} & \vphantom{X}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
This is not indented.
\lipsum*[2] This is illustrated in the following diagram:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5em,row sep=3em]
{} \arrow[r,"\textstyle\textbf{Compile}"]
   \arrow[dr,swap,"\textstyle\textbf{Interpret}"]
&
{} \arrow[d,"\textstyle\textbf{Run}"]
\\
{} & \vphantom{X}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

This is indented. \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]